# Accessing callee on Typescript strict mode functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm adding functions to [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/is) that access`arugments.callee`.  Within the project's `tsconfig.json` I set `"strict": false`, causing this mini test to work:

```
    function check() {
        console.log(arguments.callee.name);
    }
```

That works.  Now if I import the part of the library that I want to run tests on like this:

```
    import {isNumberInRange} from './is';

    function check() {
        console.log(arguments.callee.name);
    //    isNumberInRange(1,0,1);
    }
    check();
```

Even if I don't actually run the `isNumberInRange` function typescript still logs this:

> TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
>       at check (/home/ole/Github/is/src/test.ts:4:27)

What else do I need to do to enable calling `arguments.callee.name`?

Comment: It would be worth your while to review this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript

Comment: Already did ...

Comment: well, you already answered your own question; remove strict mode.

Comment: As I noted in the question, strict mode is removed.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269478/prevent-use-strict-in-typescript

Comment: Bullseye!!  Nice - Thanks!  My eye brow was starting to twitch over this one.  Please answer the question and I'll check it off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to `"strict": false` also add `"noImplicitUseStrict": true`.

TypeScript will add strict mode in on it's own, and this needs to be disabled.

How to do this has been answered already here: [prevent-use-strict-in-typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269478/prevent-use-strict-in-typescript)

> You can do that by compiling with the --noImplicitUseStrict compiler option—add "noImplicitUseStrict": true to "compilerOptions" in tsconfig.json. Doing so will prevent the compiler from emitting "use strict".