# Not able access function after eval()

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

Due to some reason, I am require to use the eval() and access the function i.e. `foo`. However, I not able to make it in typescript.

```
eval("function foo() { console.log(\"foo bar\") }");
// @ts-ignore
foo();
```

The above code will hit error instead of print "foo bar" in console log.

```
VM42:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

You may try the code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=7&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYNwhgNgFARAZgVwHYGMAuBLA9kgBHLLKASlwG9cUcBnLCYAOgiwHMoAdeQ3AIzACdOpAL4xiAbgBQAemm4AAmmoBaDCyRZ+wSQSISgA).

However, the same code work in [javascript](https://js.do/code/423474).

Does it require additional configuration?

Comment: Seems like it's just how the TS Playground executes your code. I don't think it's TypeScript specific. As always, I must urge against using `eval` if it's not really needed, though. The issue here might be a side-effect but `eval` is best avoided anyway.

Comment: Actually, I hit the same issue in my ReactJs TypeScript project as well. So I find a simple example to simulate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implied `"use strict"` of TypeScript puts heavy restrictions on `eval`, notably its [inability to create new symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Simplifying_variable_uses). You would need to explicitly return and assign the function from `eval`:

```js
"use strict"

const foo = eval("function foo() { console.log(\"foo bar\") }; foo;");

foo();
```

Comment: Using hoist can do. 
`let foo;
eval("function foo() { console.log(\"foo bar\") }");
// @ts-ignore
foo();`

Comment: Nope, not in *strict mode.*

Comment: For typescript, is it possible to partially disable the 'use strict' for a single code block?

Comment: @karfai I believe you can only [*globally* disable it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38270418/476), which certainly isn't a good idea. Just appending `+ '; foo;'` to your string and using the above solution is the most sensible solution, if you have to use `eval` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

// You can define in window/global. that will be accesable anywhere.

// You can `hoist` function. Cheat

```
let foo;
eval('function foo() { console.log("foo bar") };');

// @ts-ignore
foo();
```

// For browser add in window,

```
eval("function foo() { console.log(\"foo bar\") }; window.foo = foo");

// @ts-ignore
foo();
```

// For nodejs add in window,

```
eval("function foo() { console.log(\"foo bar\") }; global.foo = foo");

// @ts-ignore
foo();
```

Comment: Is there any work around without edit the eval content?

Comment: @karfai I found it, try to hoist :-D