# How can I access "this" in Typescript in the same way as I do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

in js, i use following code

```
function m() {
  console.log(this)
}

m()
```

this return current context

but in ts, I use following code, this return undefine

```
function m() {
    // @ts-ignore
    console.log(this)
}

m()
```

I hope use this get current context in typescript, how to do?

Comment: might wanna also read https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript

Comment: Related (and also a possible solution): [Prevent "use strict" in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269478/prevent-use-strict-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of 'use strict' which used in your typescript by default.

if you try this in js returns the same undefined

```
'use strict';

function m() {
  console.log(this)
}

m()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you use TS you are running in strict mode and, in strict mode, `this` of a function is undefined.

> Thus for a strict mode function, the specified this is not boxed into
> an object, and if unspecified, this will be undefined:

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Comment: And any decent JavaScript developer was running in strict mode before they switched to TypeScript unless they had a specific and well defined reason for not doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers tell you, it's because of the `use strict` of typescript. To be able to have a `this` context, you can (but shouldn't) use the `new` keyword.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwBQEpEG8BQj+ID0hiAAlAM4C0MA5mHAE4CmeBECFcANswHTc4tVAHIoACxgURAGkQSp6ANw4AvjhzEylGvSaswzAO4oMSoA)

```
function m() {
  // @ts-ignore
  console.log(this);
}

// @ts-ignore
new m();
```

Comment: Or set `"alwaysStrict"` false in compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try Like this,

```
const that = this;

function m() {
  console.log(that);
}

m();
```